# Displaying output in shiny main panel of the shiny UI (code is running without any error still result is not displayed on the UI)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a UI on which I can upload a file and also there is a text input where I can write the product name which I want to search in the uploaded file. I am doing that using the Levenshtein Distance function (adist() function). Now, once i get the results for which the edit distance is 0, I want to display those rows in the Table on the Main Panel. Whatever input is given in the Text input on the UI is searched against the items column in the file uploaded. A sample image of the CSV file which is uploaded is this-

[Sample image of the CSV file which is input by the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3d2n.jpg)

Once I run the code and find the edit distance for all the words, I store them in a vector and then use this to print the rows from the file which have edit distance equal to 0. The problem is that when I click on submit, the result is not displayed on the UI but it is displayed on the R-studio console. How do I fix this?

Please help me with the code.

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("LEVENSHTEIN DISTANCE function trial"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("rows","Enter the number of rows",value=NULL),
      textInput("product", "input product name"),
      br(),
      br(),
      fileInput("file", "Input the file"),
      submitButton("Find!")),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("result")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  output$result <- renderPrint({ if (is.null(input$file)) return( ); 
    trial = read.csv(input$file$datapath)

    ls = vector('list', length = input$rows)

    for(i in 1:input$rows) {
      edit = adist("earbuds", trial$items[i])
      new_edit = as.numeric(edit)
      ls[i] = edit
      if(ls[i]==0) print(trial[i, ])
    }

  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display the Edit Distance results on the shiny UI in R-studio and how to run the process in Parallel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648207/display-the-edit-distance-results-on-the-shiny-ui-in-r-studio-and-how-to-run-the)

Comment: That question is deleted

Comment: can you help please?

Comment: The problem is when I click on submit, the result is not displayed on the UI but it is displayed on the R-studio console. How do I fix this?
Please help @Pascal

Comment: renderTable expects an object that is a compatible table. You are printing the output to console in the loop. I suggest you first test your UI by replacing all your code in renderTable with a simple data frame. Once that works, you can fix your server code to pass correct end result to renderTable.

Comment: @user3949008 Thanks for replying.  When I replaced the renderTable by renderPrint, it started printing the rows on the main panel but it is just printing the rows one after the other. I want the result in a tabular form. How do I do that?

Comment: Then, you need to gather all the rows into a table (data frame or data table).

Comment: @user3949008 I am sorry but I dont know how to do that. Can you help? If possible can you run the code and tell me what I should change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very hard to provide working code without sample input date. But, here is my attempt at giving you what I think should work.

```
server = shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  output$result <- renderTable({
    if (!is.null(input$file)) { 
      trial = read.csv(input$file)
      trial <- trial[adist('earbuds', trial$items) == 0), ]
    }
  })
})
```

If you provide input data and expected output table, I can edit the answer to be more precise.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. This solved my problem and gave me the desired output. Thanks a ton!